# Calling python packages from different folders without installing them from

Tags: python

I wrote two python packages, let's name them package1 and package2. package1 depends on package2. The simulations I want to run need both packages. Therefore I created a folder /simulations/ and made it the project folder in pycharm. In this folder I put the two packages in the folders /simulations/folder1/ and /simulations/folder2/. I have a script /simulations/simulation.py in which I call functions from both packages. So far so good. The problem I now have is the following: the code of both packages are in the sub folders /simulations/folder1/package1/ and /simulations/folder2/package2/ folder. Inside these /simulations/folder1/ I can call functions via

from package1.script1 import func1

But I want to call functions from /simulations/simulation.py. There I have to import them as

from folder1.package1.script1 import func1,

which is ok. But script1 also calls functions (from package1.script2 import func2). But it cannot do that because pycharm thinks always that the path starts in the /simulations/ folder...

Is there a possibility how I don't have to change all paths in all of the files? Is there a standard how to do this properly?

Comment: I have a [tutorial](https://github.com/embray/notebooks/blob/master/simcluster.ipynb) I like to give on how to package Python packages properly.  Part 6 is where it becomes particularly relevant to your question.  It *should* answer your question "Is there a standard how to do this properly?"  One aspect of it that's a bit out of date and needs updating: Generally it's not a good idea, once you have a `setup.py`, to run `setup.py install directly`.  In this case, for doing development, run `pip install -e .` instead.  It will install the package in editable develop mode.

Comment: One other thing I don't really talk about in the tutorial is using "virtualenvs" (see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments)  If you don't want to "install" things into your main Python installation this is the way to go, especially for development.  With a virtualenv activated, `pip install -e` will only add your packages to the virtual environment you use for development.  In general this is a much better way to go about things that worrying about what modules are in what paths and whether those paths are all on `sys.path`, etc.